# cordova and crashlytics beta build script

Tags: android, cordova, crashlytics

I am trying to write a script file that builds my apk and uploads it to Crashlytics beta without success.

```
echo "\n > cordova build android\n"
cordova build android --release

echo "\n > signing apk\n"
jarsigner \
  -storepass $STOREPASS \
  -sigalg SHA1withRSA \
  -digestalg SHA1 \
  -keystore $KEYSTORE \
  $APK_PATH \
  $NAME

mkdir -p releases
zipalign -f -v 4 \
  $APK_PATH \
  $TARGET_PATH
```

the script works perfectly but when I run

```
java -jar scripts/crashlytics-devtools.jar \
  -projectPath $PROJECT_PATH \
  -androidManifest $PROJECT_PATH/AndroidManifest.xml \
  -androidRes $PROJECT_PATH/res \
  -androidAssets $PROJECT_PATH/assets \
  -apiKey $FABRIC_API_KEY \
  -apiSecret $FABRIC_BUILD_SECRET \
  -uploadDist $APK \
  -verbose
```

it gives me a `Exception in thread "main" com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools$PluginException: Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't extract Crashlytics build info from the APK`

Any help?

Comment: Did you get any solutions? I face the same issue and no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by…

1. Installing fabric into `platforms/android/build.gradle`
2. Installing the Fabric plugin

   https://github.com/engincancan/cordova-fabric-io-plugin

To install Fabric into the `build.gradle` I did the following…

1. Install Android Studio.
2. Install the Fabric plugin for Android Studio.
3. Open the project in `platforms/android` in Android Studio.
4. Click on the Fabric button in the toolbar, sign in and go through the installation wizard.

The wizard tells you what it is adding to the project so, if you are really motivated, you could write your own script to do the same thing. This would mean that you could build from the command line without checking in `platforms/android`.

Afterwards the script you provided works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like during your build process you should be installing the cordova plugin.

Try doing one of these (ionic uses cordova and here for archival sake):

```
# via command line install
cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=${FABRIC_API_KEY} --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=${FABRIC_BUILD_SECRET}

# install from source
cordova plugin add https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin#x.x.x  --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=${FABRIC_API_KEY} --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=${FABRIC_BUILD_SECRET}

# using ionic
ionic plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=${FABRIC_API_KEY} --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=${FABRIC_BUILD_SECRET}
```

Your script would then look something like this:

```
# now execute the commands in your script
cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=${FABRIC_API_KEY} --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=${FABRIC_BUILD_SECRET}

java -jar scripts/crashlytics-devtools.jar \
  -projectPath $PROJECT_PATH \
  -androidManifest $PROJECT_PATH/AndroidManifest.xml \
  -androidRes $PROJECT_PATH/res \
  -androidAssets $PROJECT_PATH/assets \
  -apiKey $FABRIC_API_KEY \
  -apiSecret $FABRIC_BUILD_SECRET \
  -uploadDist $APK \
  -verbose
```